# Deallocation of Azure VM on a task completion

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation

I need an Azure VM (Ubuntu) to do some task (java application) every 10 minutes. Because the task lasts usually less than a minute I would save money if could start the machine every 10 minutes and stop it when the task accomplishes. I learned that I can schedule start and stop times in automation account, but more optimal would be to stop the VM in the very moment that task is completed. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a job for Azure Batch. If you are looking for an IaaS solution, Azure Batch will do the job for you. Have a look at it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/batch/#overview.
It allows you to use VM's with your preferred OS (in Azure Batch it is called a node), and run a set of tasks. Once finished, the VM will be de-allocated.

So each node runs a set of pools, in each pool you have a job, and in each job you can have tasks. A task can be for example a cmd line that runs a specific app. So for instance you could just `run example.exe 1 2` on a windows OS or the equivalent command line for an Ubuntu OS.

The power here is that it will allocate the tasks to run on the VM when you add them to the job, and then the VM will be disposed off once finished, and you would only pay for the compute time.

The disadvantages of this is that it is a stateless VM, therefore anything that you need installing or storing you would have to use alternative methods. Azure Batch allows you to pre-install a program (for example your Java application) each time it initiates. Also if you are using files and/or expecting files to be created, you would need a blob storage to support this. So if you are expecting it to use a certain amount of files, store them on blob storage and then write back to the blob storage if your program is doing this.

Finally your scheduler, this really depends on how you want to deal with it, if you have a local server or a server on Azure that is already running 24/7 you can add a scheduled job to the scheduler and run a program that will add the task to the Azure Batch. Or if you don't mind using Azure Functions, you can just add a timer Azure Function that will add a task to the job. There are multiple ways of dealing with this, you may already have an existing solution.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Azure Batch looks like something that can do the job, however I found another solution. I can use Automation Account and call webhook to triger VM stop from inside VM after my task is completed. It appears simple. It would save time to learn the whole Azure Batch stuff. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think VM + Automation Account is essentially the same an Azure Batch. You may save some money with Azure Batch as you are not paying for the VM's but just the compute time, where every time you allocate the VM you pay for the infrastructure also and it may turn more expensive. I guess you would need to run some estimates if you are really interested in going the extra mile. But if you have found a similar approach and you are already saving, I doubt you will save much more with Azure Batch. Also worth mentioning that Azure Batch has low priority VM allocation: cheaper compute time.